# Package name for Spring MVC helper class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, naming-conventions

I am creating a .jsp page where user can pick two dates to retrieve database records added between these two dates.

To take advantage of Spring features (like validation) I must assign a `commandName` attribute in my form, so I need a new class. I created a class which stores 2 dates:

```
public class DatePicker {
    private String startingDate;
    private String endingDate;
}
```

Where should that class be located in my project? I currently have following packages:

`controller`, `model`, `dao`, `exception`

The `DatePicker` class obviously needs a new package- what is a proper name for such package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we put this classed in a package named "wrapper". because it wraps the properties for the jsp page

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.